# Slick2d - state change problem

Tags: 2d, slick, game-state

In my slick-based game, I have 4 states - introState, gameState, pauseState and menuState.

From the gameState, I want player to go to **either menuState or pauseState**.
To do that, I did this in gameState:-

```
public void changeState(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
    {
        sbg.enterState(2);
    }
    else if(input.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE))
    {
        sbg.enterState(3);
    }
}
```

To return from pauseState to gameState, I did this in pauseState:-

```
public void changeState(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
    {
        sbg.enterState(1);
    }
}
```

To return from menuState to gameState, I did this in menuState:-

```
public void changeState(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE))
    {
        sbg.enterState(1);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want player to go to **either pauseState or menuState from the gameState** and not from pauseState to menuState or vice-versa.

Unfortunately, due to some unknown reason, when i press escape, it enters pauseState correctly but then if i press spacebar and then press enter, instead of going to gameState it goes to menuState. Any idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself:-
*Before going to a different state, use the **input.clearKeyPressedRecord()** to clear all previously recorded key-Presses, or else even after changing a state, previously stored keyPress event will cause problems.*

So instead of doing this,

```
public void changeState(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
    {
        sbg.enterState(1);
    }
}
```

Do this:

```
public void changeState(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
    {
        input.clearKeyPressedRecord();
        sbg.enterState(1);
    }
}
```